# English standard of the (Prose) Edda?

Tags: translation, myths, norse-mythology

Gustav Schwab‘s *[Gods and Heroes of Ancient Greece](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/431071.Gods_and_Heroes_of_Ancient_Greece)* (OT: *Die schönsten klassischen Sagen des Altertums*) is at least to the German audience **the** encyclopaedia of Roman and Greek mythology (despite its title). [Gustav Schwab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustav_Schwab) translated and adapted the most famous works (Aeneid, Iliad etc.) of the ancient world.

This is somewhat similar to Sioned Davies’ version of the old Welsh [*Mabinogion*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/36794219-the-mabinogion?ac=1&from_search=true): It’s a modern adaptation (and translation) of **the** Welsh myths.

The Edda is the “bible” of Nordic and Icelandic myths. Does there exist an equivalent to the other two works (an English translation into Prose that is accepted as the standard encyclopaedia for Nordic Myths)?

Comment: If that is too much of a book recommendation, let me know and I’ll take it down

Comment: The [Prose Edda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prose_Edda) or the [Poetic Edda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poetic_Edda)?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe The prose Edda.